# Arguments to sidekiq worker method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I am using `sidekiq` to perform some background job, but have some doubts in passing arguments to `perform` method of `sidekiq's` worker class.

**Scenario:**
As soon as user enters into my application i am storing log information in to my model `user_sessions`.

As-usual performing dedicated action in my controller. But after displaying information to the user i need to perform some extra operation and needs to update one column in `user_session` model.

Followed procedure mentioned [here](http://sidekiq.org/)

step 1: Added `gem 'sidekiq'` to gem file.

step 2: Installed `'redis'` gem.

step 3: bundle install

step 4:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
 def MyAction
  #perform dedicated action
  @info = #render data to user
  param1 = #parameter to find in user_session model(its a string.i don't get id of model here)
  param2 = #extra param to perform task
  UpdateWorker.perform_async(param1,param2)
 end
end
```

step 5: Created a worker folder under app folder.

```
class UpdateWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    def perform(param1,param2)
        puts "======> updating "
        #retrieve `user_session` based on param1(note: param1 is not an id)
        #perform update functions
        UserSession.update_attribute(:column, value)
    end
end
```

step 6: Started `rails server`

step 7: In another tab started `bundle exec sidekiq`

Error `NoMethodError (undefined method 'key?' for JSON::Ext::Generator::State:0x007f1b......`

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158057/sidekiq-mailer-error-when-trying-to-send-email) and [here](https://github.com/resque/resque/issues/810#issuecomment-39385555) i need to pass object's id in parameters.
As for my scenario can anyone suggest me how to solve my problem?

Comment: Do i need to downgrade my multi-json version?

Comment: So the first thing to do is to log the type of param1 and param2 in the Controller.  It's almost certain that you're passing a complex, non-serializable object to Sidekiq.

Comment: @PeterGoldstein being a newbie i understood little what you commented. Can you explain little more about that.Please?

Comment: In the controller, right before the UpdateWorker line add the following - `logger.error "Param 1: #{param1.class.name} Param2: #{param2.class.name}"`.  That will tell you exactly what you're passing to the UpdateWorker.perform method.

Comment: one is of type string and one is of type integer

Comment: And you are certain there are no old jobs hanging around where you didn't use the string and integer?  Redis is empty?  You can confirm this by using the Sidekiq web UI.

Answer (score 4):

This would be better way :

```
array = [param1,param2]

UpdateWorker.perform_async(array)
```

Now in worker you can use array